# Android Smartband2 Reader in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This code was written a long time ago but has probably gotten a bit deprecated now and I wonder how it can be improved. It's for an xamarin cross-platform project for IOS and Android but this part is just for the android. The goal is for the app to read the step_count data from the smartband.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Fitness.Request;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Gms.Fitness;
using Android.Gms.Fitness.Data;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Util;

namespace BasicSensorsApi
{
    [Activity (MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity
    {
        public const string TAG = "BasicSensorsApi";

        const int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;

        const string AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
        bool authInProgress;

        GoogleApiClient mClient;

        IOnDataPointListener mListener;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            InitializeLogging();

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                authInProgress = savedInstanceState.GetBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
            }

            BuildFitnessClient();
        }


        void BuildFitnessClient ()
        {
            var clientConnectionCallback = new ClientConnectionCallback ();
            clientConnectionCallback.OnConnectedImpl = () => FindFitnessDataSources ();
            mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (this)
                .AddApi (FitnessClass.SENSORS_API)
                .AddScope (new Scope (Scopes.FitnessLocationRead))
                .AddConnectionCallbacks (clientConnectionCallback)
                .AddOnConnectionFailedListener ((ConnectionResult result) => {
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result);
                    if (!result.HasResolution) {
                        // Show the localized error dialog
                        GooglePlayServicesUtil.GetErrorDialog (result.ErrorCode, this, 0).Show ();
                                return;
                    }
                    if (!authInProgress) {
                        try {
                            Log.Info (TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                            authInProgress = true;
                            result.StartResolutionForResult (this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.Error (TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                        }
                    }
                }).Build ();
        }

        class ClientConnectionCallback : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks
        {
            public Action OnConnectedImpl { get; set; }

            public void OnConnected (Bundle connectionHint)
            {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Connected!!!");

                OnConnectedImpl();
            }

            public void OnConnectionSuspended (int cause)
            {
                if (cause == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CauseNetworkLost) {
                    Log.Info (TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                } else if (cause == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CauseServiceDisconnected) {
                    Log.Info (TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            base.OnStart ();
            Log.Info (TAG, "Connecting...");
            mClient.Connect ();
        }

        protected override void OnStop ()
        {
            base.OnStop ();
            if (mClient.IsConnected) {
                mClient.Disconnect ();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
                authInProgress = false;
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
                    if (!mClient.IsConnecting && !mClient.IsConnected) {
                        mClient.Connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
        {
            base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
            outState.PutBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
        }

        async Task FindFitnessDataSources ()
        {
            var dataSourcesResult = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.FindDataSourcesAsync (mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder ()
                .SetDataTypes (Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeLocationSample)
                .SetDataSourceTypes (DataSource.TypeRaw)
                .Build ());

            Log.Info (TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.Status);
            foreach (DataSource dataSource in dataSourcesResult.DataSources) {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource);
                Log.Info (TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.DataType.Name);

                //Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                if (dataSource.DataType == Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeLocationSample && mListener == null) {
                    Log.Info (TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                    await RegisterFitnessDataListener (dataSource, Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeLocationSample);
                }
            }
        }

        async Task RegisterFitnessDataListener (DataSource dataSource, Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType dataType)
        {
            // [START register_data_listener]
            mListener = new OnDataPointListener ();
            var status = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.AddAsync (mClient, new SensorRequest.Builder ()
                .SetDataSource (dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                .SetDataType (dataType) // Can't be omitted.
                .SetSamplingRate (10, TimeUnit.Seconds)
                .Build (),
                mListener);
            if (status.IsSuccess) {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Listener registered!");
            } else {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Listener not registered.");
            }
        }

        class OnDataPointListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnDataPointListener
        {
            public void OnDataPoint (DataPoint dataPoint)
            {
                foreach (var field in dataPoint.DataType.Fields) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.GetValue(field);
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.Name);
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
                }
            }

        }

        async Task UnregisterFitnessDataListener ()
        {
            if (mListener == null) {
                return;
            }

            var status = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.RemoveAsync (mClient, mListener);

            if (status.IsSuccess) {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Listener was removed!");
            } else {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Listener was not removed.");
            }

        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.action_unregister_listener) {
                await async UnregisterFitnessDataListener();
                return true;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
        }

        void InitializeLogging ()
        {
            // Wraps Android's native log framework.
            var logWrapper = new LogWrapper ();
            // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
            Log.LogNode = logWrapper;
            // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
            var msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter ();
            logWrapper.NextNode = msgFilter;
            // On screen logging via a customized TextView.
            var logView = FindViewById<LogView> (Resource.Id.sample_logview);
            logView.SetTextAppearance (this, Resource.Style.Log);
            logView.SetBackgroundColor (Color.White);
            msgFilter.NextNode = logView;
            Log.Info (TAG, "Ready");
        }
    }
}
```